# How to create a direct integral macro

Tags: macros

There's a symbol that's commonly used in an area of math I'm working in, called the direct integral, which is often written as `\int^\oplus`. I think it would be aesthetically nicer if the `\oplus` was actually in the middle of the integral sign, as is the case for the `\oint` symbol, but there isn't any LaTeX symbol I know of that does that automatically. I tried to create my own macro for this by writing `\oplus\hspace{-1.12em}\int`, but this only works well in display equations, and the sizes and positions don't fit together in inline equations. Is there any good way of creating a new LaTeX symbol or macro that would display this?

Comment: Can you point to some online resource where the symbol you'd prefer is actually used?

Comment: No, I don’t know of it being used. I’m interested in this problem purely because I’m curious if it’s possible to create an aesthetically nicer symbol than the current one.

Comment: [This is the output (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6a6G.png). I don't think there is any real improvement possible: the vertical bar in the `\oplus` will always clash with the integral symbol some way or the other. For smaller sizes it is even worse.

Comment: I’ve also thought about using an ominus instead, since the difference would be very slight. My main concern is just that for inline equations, the oplus/ominus tends to move quite a bit horizontally, and is much too big.

Comment: You can use `\mathchoice` to help you use different amounts of negative space depending on the style. Also, I'd suggest using `\mkern` (with units of `mu`) for the negative space. And expect the result to be highly font dependent! If you change the math font, you will have to change the spacing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best I can offer is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\directint}{\mathop{\mathpalette\direct@int\relax}\!\int}
\newcommand{\direct@int}[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{%
    \m@th
    \ooalign{%
      \hidewidth$\demote@style{#1}{\bigoplus}$\hidewidth\cr
      $#1\phantom{\int}$\cr
    }%
  }%
  \wd\z@=\z@\box\z@
}
\newcommand{\demote@style}[2]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\scriptstyle#2\else
    \raise.5\fontdimen22\textfont2\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle#2$}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\displaystyle\directint_X$ \qquad $\directint_X$

\end{document}
```

It doesn't work in subscripts, but I don't think working on it is worth the pain, because the symbol is ugly and, as you say, not used in the literature.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Another solution, based on `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{stackengine} 

\newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}} 
\newcommand\directint{\mathop{\stackMath{\stackinset{c}{0.05ex}{c}{0ex}{\scriptscriptstyle\boldsymbol\oplus}{\displaystyle\int}}}}

\begin{document}

        \[ \displaystyle\directint A_x\dd\mu(x) \]

\end{document}
```

[image]